# How can I list all uploads for a project?

Tags: api, file-upload, gitlab

I would like to access the list of all uploads that have been added to a given project on my company GitLab server.

I don't mean *versionned* files, I mean *attached* files: binaries and other types of files that have been attached to issues, merge requests, etc.

It's OK if I have to use the API for that.

### What I've tried

My first approach was through [`GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html), but that's for the versionned files.

Then, I found out about [`POST /projects/:id/uploads`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#upload-a-file), but that's only for uploading and not for listing already uploaded files.

Is there a way to list all those uploaded files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not possible.
There is an open issue for retrieving specific files which has not received much attention:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/55520

Hopefully, in the future, there will eventually be an endpoint

```
GET /projects/:id/uploads
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and after getting in touch with gitlab support they confirmed that this is not currently implemented (as of now, November 2021), and forwarded me the 3 following feature requests :

- API list all files on a project : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/197361
- Attachment Manager : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16229
- Retrieve uploaded files using API : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/25838

A workaround seems to be to export the whole project, and you'll find the uploads in that archive, and you'll be able to list them.